# Android FragmentStatePagerAdapter for custom View

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

because I don't like the default implementation of Android's Bottom Navigation Bar, I have made my own and connected it with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I just want to know how I can get already created Fragments with their saved instance state from my adapter just like viewpager does?
It would be nice if anyone could help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own. I totally had forgotten to care about the Saved Instance State of my view. I got it from the ViewPager source code and modified it slightly because some  Methods were marked as deprecated. Here the implementation.

```
@Nullable
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    SaveState ss = new SaveState(superState);
    ss.position = lastSelectedPosition;
    ss.itemId = lastSelectedItemId;
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        ss.adapterState = mAdapter.saveState();
    }
    return ss;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (!(state instanceof SaveState)) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }
    SaveState ss = (SaveState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.restoreState(ss.adapterState, ss.loader);
        setSelectedItem(ss.position, ss.itemId);
        lastSelectedItemId = ss.itemId;
        lastSelectedPosition = ss.position;
    }
}

public static class SaveState extends BaseSavedState {
    int position;
    int itemId;
    Parcelable adapterState;
    ClassLoader loader;

    SaveState(Parcelable superState) {
        super(superState);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeInt(position);
        out.writeInt(itemId);
        out.writeParcelable(adapterState, flags);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<SaveState> CREATOR = new 
    Class later dater<SaveState>() {
        @Override
        public SaveState createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new SaveState(source, null);
        }

        @Override
        public SaveState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SaveState[size];
        }

        @Override
        public SaveState createFromParcel(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader) {
            return new SaveState(source, loader);
        }
    };

    SaveState(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader) {
        super(in);
        if (loader == null) {
            loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        }
        position = in.readInt();
        itemId = in.readInt();
        adapterState = in.readParcelable(loader);
        this.loader = loader;
    }

}
```